# Random 0-1 matrices

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

For $n,r∈N$, $1<r<n$, let $z(r,n)$ be the largest possible number of 0 entries in an $n×n$ matrix which has no $r×r$ submatrix whose entries are all $0$. (Here a submatrix is obtained by selecting any $r$ rows and any $r$ columns; the rows/columns need not be consecutive.)

Consider a random matrix in which each entry is  $0$ with probability $p$ and $1$ with probability $1−p$, independently.

Deduce that $z(r,n)>pn^{2}−p^{r^{2}}n^{2r}$.
My solution:

Let $[n]_{2}$ denote the set of all $n×n$ matrices, with only $0−1$ entries. For each $σ∈[n]_{2}$ let the random variable $X(σ)$ denote the number of $0$ entries in $σ$ and the random variable $Y(σ)$ denote the number of $r×r$ submatrices filled with entirely with $0$'s. It follows that $\mathbb{E}(X)=pn^{2}$ and $\mathbb{E}(Y)=\binom{n}{r}^{2}p^{r^{2}}<n^{2r}p^{r^{2}}$ .

Further more consider the random variable $X−Y$ for which $\mathbb{E}(X-Y)>pn^{2}-n^{2r}p^{r^{2}}$. It follows that there exists a $σ∈[n]_{2}$ such that $X(σ)−Y(σ)>pn^{2}-n^{2r}p^{r^{2}}$. Given such a $σ$ construct $σ′∈[n]_{2}$ as follows. For each of the all $0$, $r×r$ sub matrices of $σ$ remove at random a single $0$ from each to ensure $σ′$ has no $r×r$ such sub-matrices. Then we have removed at most $\binom{n}{r}^{2}<n^{2r}$ such zero's and so we can conclude that $σ′$ has at least $pn^{2}-n^{2r}p^{r^{2}}$ zeros thus we can conclude that $z(n,r)>pn^{2}-n^{2r}p^{r^{2}}$.

Id appreciate any comments on the validity of the proof.